# what is order of implementation of matrix transforms?

Tags: graphics, matrix

What is the meaning of Tr*Sh*Ro*Sc =M ?

1. How is matrix `M` written to form the graphic transformation :  1st Sc=Scale, 2nd: R=Rotate, 3rd : Sh=Shear 4th: T=Translate ?
2. Is the matrix  M above written properly in a "post multiplcative" format" T*Sh*R*Sc , but executed  Scale, Rotate, Shear , finaly Translate ?

Comment: Hi @martymarty, I removed the parts of your question that polled for tutorial recommendations; those questions are generally outside preferred format for posts here.  As for question about matrices, what are you trying to accomplish?  You are asking about a fairly abstract quality of transformation matrices, but understanding those aspects should be a simple matter of studying ([even wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)).  Is there something in particular you want to understand?  What new insight do you want to gain?

Comment: Only a partial answer to your question, but something I wrote a while back since I sometimes have trouble keeping it all straight in my head: http://seanmiddleditch.com/journal/2012/08/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/

Answer (score 1):

The Graphics Programming community generally uses *row vectors*, that *pre-multiply* the transformation matrix as:

> v * ( T * Sh * R * Sc).

The Mathematics and Physics communities generally uses *column vectors* that *post-multiply* the transformation matrix as:

> ( T * Sh * R * Sc) * v

Both approaches are equivalent, but of course they cannot be mixed. Choose one and stick with it in order to stay out of trouble.

**Update**:

Sean Middletech's [blog link](http://seanmiddleditch.com/journal/2012/08/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/) above is excellent; well-written and clear, both mathematically sound and accessible by the programmer with weaker math skills. I reproduce it [here](http://seanmiddleditch.com/journal/2012/08/matrices-handedness-pre-and-post-multiplication-row-vs-column-major-and-notations/) in case the comment disappears at some point in the future.

Comment: from my experience the graphics community prefer column notation :)

Comment: @concept3d: Interesting. Traditionally, I believe that to not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add imaginary parentheses to understand what's going on.

If `M = Tr*Sh*Ro*Sc` and `P' = M*P`, scale happens first because

`P' = Tr*Sh*Ro*Sc*P = Tr*Sh*Ro*(Sc*P)`

In fact,

`P' = Tr*Sh*Ro*Sc*P = Tr*Sh*Ro*(Sc*P) = Tr*Sh*(Ro*(Sc*P)) = Tr*(Sh*(Ro*(Sc*P)))`

You're composing transforms here. The result of one transform is fed into the next. Yet another way to think about it:

`P1 = Sc*P`

`P2 = Ro*P1`

`P3 = Sh*P2`

`P' = Tr*P3`